# Looking for Gallery Plugin

Tags: plugins

im looking for wordpress plugin for small work.

I want to have a folder with images inside, i want to move that folder at some directory and auto create gallery post.

For example i have folder named "Winter 2018" and 10 images inside, when move that folder i want to auto-create new post with featured image from those images and title extracted from folder "winter 2018"

Is there any plugin that can create auto-posts from directory folders ?

Answer (score 2):

Below are some possible plugins for your need:

- [NextGen Gallery](https://www.imagely.com/wordpress-gallery-plugin/) - This includes both a zip importer/batch file uploader with option to assign a subfolder for the zip/batch of images and a folder importer feature. The plugin is well maintained, but may require one of the premium version extensions to include all the gallery importer options.
- [WonderPlugin Gallery](https://www.wonderplugin.com/wordpress-tutorials/wordpress-folder-gallery-how-to-create-a-wordpress-gallery-from-a-folder-on-web-server/) - This includes a folder importer and shortcode to drop on a page.  It's a commercial plugin, but you can demo the free version which puts its watermark on the images.
- [Enhanced Media Library](https://wordpress.org/plugins/enhanced-media-library/) - This can be used to add taxonomies/categories and bulk assign them to your images, the importer is for importing images exported from another Wordpress site (and stored in the generic uploads folder).  You'd still have to manually code a template that can loop through and render all the images with a particular taxonomy term assigned to them.

You can find a similar question on [here on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15703189/how-organize-uploaded-media-in-wp), but with a dated response.